# Strange behaviour of <select> based product filters causing empty select boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently struggling hard with Angular 1.4. Since I'm coming from the React world I don't know all base concepts of Angular yet.

I'm trying to build a (I thought) simple product filtering UI.

[image]

As you can see, I currently have 3 select boxes. The two upper ones are responsible for filtering a list of products by specific product attributes (dimension/aspect-ratio and production type).

The bottom one will hold the updated, filtered list of items and is updated dynamically when the two upper ones are changed.

My issue is that I can actually filter correctly as long as I don't change the product-selectbox manually. After changing it manually, each filtering will trigger the model to update (I presume) which causes the selectbox to be empty since it can't find the product. It should actually pick the first item of the new selectbox values by when the filters are changed.

The markup for the select boxes looks like the following:

```
     <div class="productDetails-options">
       <div class="productDetails-optionGroup" ng-repeat="(key, filter) in filters">
         <select class="productDetails-optionDropdown"
           ng-options="item as item.name for item in filter.items"
           ng-model="currentFilters[key]"
           ng-change="changeCurrentFilter()"></select>
       </div>

       <div class="productDetails-optionGroup">
         <select class="productDetails-optionDropdown"
           ng-options="product.id as product.title for product in filteredProducts"
           ng-model="currentProductID"
           ng-change="changeCurrentProduct(currentProductID)">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And the Controller functions look like this:

```
    var getFilteredProducts = function () {
        var products = $scope.source.items
        var filteredProducts = {}

        for (var key in products) {
            var product = products[key]
            var available = true

            for (var filterKey in product.filter) {
                var productFilter = product.filter[filterKey]

                if (productFilter.indexOf($scope.currentFilters[filterKey].id) === -1) {
                    available = false
                }
            }

            if (available) {
                filteredProducts[key] = product
            }
        }

        return filteredProducts
    }

    var getCurrentProductFromFirstElement = function () {
        const firstProduct = Object.values($scope.filteredProducts)[0]
        $scope.currentProductID = firstProduct.id
        $scope.currentProduct = firstProduct
    }

    $scope.changeCurrentFilter = function () {
        $scope.filteredProducts = getFilteredProducts()
        getCurrentProductFromFirstElement()
    }

    $scope.changeCurrentProduct = function (newProductID) {
        if (!newProductID) {
            var productKeys = Object.keys($scope.filteredProducts)
            var firstItem = $scope.filteredProducts[productKeys[0]]
            newProductID = firstItem.id
            console.log(newProductID)
        }

        $scope.currentProduct = $scope.filteredProducts[newProductID]
        $scope.currentProductID = newProductID
    }
```

I'm seriously confused and spend almost a full day on this issue. Maybe someone can help me with this. I guess it's some special Angular case or concept since I never had this kind of issue with React or Vanilla javascript.

I'm already super thankful. I'll owe you a beer whoever helps me to solve this issue.

Comment: Will you please update the question with the following details
1. filteredProducts array
2. filters array
3. $scope.source array
 and other details if i missed anything in order to make it standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Put `id` for your dynamic select box's and let me know if it is works or not.

```
<select class="productDetails-optionDropdown" id={{currentFilters[key]}}
           ng-options="item as item.name for item in filter.items"
           ng-model="currentFilters[key]"
           ng-change="changeCurrentFilter()"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't changed the behaviour. It feels like changing the product select's items also triggers an ng-change which will also update the model again but I can't pinpoint down if it's true. Would `track by` have an impact? I tried using it with the `product.id` but it doesn't help neither.

Comment: Can you update your question with `changeCurrentProduct()` method?

Comment: Sure @Ramesh Rajendran I added the function.

Comment: Actually the exact problem is if you change your  3rd select box item, it will impact to the 1st and 2nd select box? Is am understand is correct? @dome2k

Comment: No the third box doesn't have any impact on the other ones. Basically the first two ones are changing the third ones `ng-options`.

Comment: @dome2k So the third one is always showing first value of `filteredProducts` object while you changing the third select box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162405/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-dome2k).